# Two variables {...} in a JSX element <...>

Tags: reactjs

I try to find out how to add two variables `{...}` into a JSX element `<...>` in an example where I need to define a key.

Something like this:

```
{data.map(entry => (
    <Item key={entry.val1}+{entry.val2}> 
  ))}
```

How to get `val1` and `val2` concatenated to the `key`?

Answer (score 0):

```
{data.map(entry => (
    <Item key={'' + entry.val1 + entry.val2}> 
  ))}
```

Here we add `''` to ensure values are concatenated, not added as numbers

Answer (score 0):

IMO the cleanest way is:

```
    {data.map(entry => (
    <Item key=`${entry.val1}${entry.val2}`> 
  ))}
```

This is called "Template literals", see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals for details.